# Add Css in Custom layout xml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I created a custom layout to display only parent categories not subcategories. But I need custom css for that layout. I create custom_layout in `Magento_Theme/page_layout` folder and defined in `layouts.xml`. Which works fine. But how I add css to that custom layout.
My custom layout is

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<update handle="1column"/>
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="category.description" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

and layouts.xml as

```
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
<layout id="category_level_one">
    <label translate="true">Category Level One</label>
</layout>
```

I need to add css like

```
<head>        
<css src="css/demo.css" media="all"/></head>
```

Which is not working. How to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you found the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

#### **In custom layout :**

If you want to add your custom css only in your custom layout, you just have to declare it in that custom layout.

**app/design/frontend/Vendor_Modulename/layout/your_custom_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/demo.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

#### **In all theme :**

**app/design/frontend/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" layout="1column">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Theme::css/demo.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

#### **Css path :**

**app/design/frontend/Magento_Theme/web/css/demo.css**

```
Your css content goes here
```

**Important :** Clean the **content** of `pub/static` without the `.htaccess` then, deploy the static content like this : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: How system know that `your_custom_layout.xml` should use?

Comment: In which page your `parent categories not subcategories..` are displayed ?

Comment: Please clear the confusion. I create custom layout in page_layout folder and register it in layouts.xml and finally backend category > design > layout select that layout. Where I need to change my work flow?

Comment: ok, add it in your theme. the 2nd case `In all theme :`

Comment: So there will be 2 files in page_layout & layout with same name right?

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your **`custom layout`**

```
<head>
    <css src="css/demo.css" media="all and (min-width: 1px)"/>
</head>
```

to be specific, add it before

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
```

Comment: Sorry Not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the **`demo.css`** file path

If the file is inside the **Magento_Theme** folder you should use like below.

> app/design/frontend/theme/Store/Magento_Theme/web/css/demo.css

```
<css src="Magento_Theme::css/demo.css" media="all"/>
```

If the file is in

> app/design/frontend/theme/Store/web/css/demo.css

Then you can use without module name like below.

```
<css src="css/demo.css" media="all"/>
```

Comment: Sorry tried not working.

Comment: share css file and xml path? did you flushed cache, static content deployed?

Comment: Magento_Theme/page_layout/custom_layout.xml, Magento_Theme/layouts.xml, Magento_Theme/web/css/demo.css

Answer (score 0):

> **First we create a custom layout, after that we add custom CSS and JS to this custom layout.**

> **Step-1 :Create layouts.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page_layouts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/PageLayout/etc/layouts.xsd">
    <layout id="customlayout">
        <label translate="true">Custom CMS Page</label>
    </layout>
</page_layouts>
```

***File name must be layout id name. Now we create customlayout.xml***

> **Step-2 : Create customlayout.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/page_layout and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="3columns"/>
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="footer-bottom" as="footer-bottom" after="footer" label="Footer Bottom" htmlTag="footer" htmlClass="page-footer-bottom">
            <container name="footer-bottom-content" as="footer-bottom-content" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs.bottom" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
</layout>
```

*You can also add your custom block and phtml file also. which are shown in Layouts when custom layout is used.*

*Now we add CSS and Js to custom layout file*

> **Step-3 : Create routes.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc/frontend and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="customlayout" id="customlayout">
            <module name="VendoreName_CustomLayout"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> **Step-4 : Create Index.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Controller/Index and add below code.**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

> **Step-5 : Create customlayout_index_index.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/layout and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::css/my_custom_layout_css.css" />
        <script src="VendoreName_CustomLayout::js/my_custom_layout_js.js" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**Here the file name must be like routename_controllername_actionname.xml and all characters must be in lowercase.**

***Add your css to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/css/my_custom_layout_css.css***

***Add your Js to app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/view/frontend/web/js/my_custom_layout_js.js***

> **Step-6 : Create events.xml file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/etc and add below code.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="custom_layout_css_js_add" instance="VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer\CustomLayoutHandler" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**we need to add to css and js before page layout that's why we use layout_load_before event.**

> **Step-7 : Create CustomLayoutHandler.php file at app/code/VendoreName/CustomLayout/Observer and add below code.**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\CustomLayout\Observer;

class CustomLayoutHandler implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $pageResult,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\Page $page
    ) {
        $this->_pageResult = $pageResult;
        $this->_page = $page;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getData('layout');
        $currentPageLayout = $this->_pageResult->getConfig()->getPageLayout();
        //$currentPageLayout = $this->_page->getPageLayout();
        if ($currentPageLayout == "customlayout") {
            $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customlayout_index_index');
        }

    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***